# Unable to resolve host name means how to resolve it in async task in android studio

Tags: java, android

Unable to resolve the host name
Following the snippet below :

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

// button to show progress dialog
Button btnShowProgress;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ImageView my_image;
// Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

// File url to download
private static String file_url = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/images/tp-logo-diamond.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your are not using internet permission in AndroidMenifext.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also ask for the same permission in runtime.